# How to customize Dialog's width?

Tags: flutter, dart

I set the dialog's width to 100, but it did not work:

```dart
void _test1() {
  showDialog(
    context: globalContext,
    builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `Dialog` source code, you can see:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**So the key to change the dialog's `width` is change it's `insetPadding` and wrap with `UnconstrainedBox`.** For example:

```dart
void _test() {
  showDialog(
    context: globalContext,
    builder: (context) {
      return UnconstrainedBox(
        constrainedAxis: Axis.vertical,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Dialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below dialog

```
 return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: Material(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                height:  350,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                
              ),
            ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the **size** variable:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

  return Scaffold(
  .
  .
```

then grab for **width** value into Dialog:

```
width: size.width,
```

now you can customize this value as you want by subtraction/minuses

i.g.: ***width: size.width - 300,***